# Explaining why Gradle reports allowInsecureProtocol error in one situation and not in the other

Tags: gradle

When updating to Gradle 7.3.3 the [allowInsecureProtocol](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol) option is one we should not need. I've updated quite a few repo's before this one , so I started updating all repositories to HTTPS.

I encountered an example where the warning still pops up unexpectedly. I'm looking for an answer to why this happens.

The example below (shortened for brevity):

```
plugins {
    id 'nebula.ospackage'
}
configurations {
    keycloak
}
dependencies {
    keycloak "keycloak:keycloak:${versions.keycloak}@zip"
}
buildRpm {
    inputs.file(configurations.keycloak.singleFile)
    // other stuff
}
```

The resulting error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':my-project'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':my-project:keycloak'.
   > Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven(http://nexus/nexus/content/groups/public/)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.
```

Whereas modifying the last bit to:

```
buildRpm {
    inputs.file(configurations.keycloak.dependencies)
    // other stuff
}
```

does not result in the error.

Funny observation to add: There is no reference anywhere in the Gradle files to http://nexus! All references are https://myurl.com/.

I'm looking for a reason for the error for `singleFile` results in the error. Thanks!

Comment: Right! Reason found: The Gradle configuration still also contained a custom plugin that was still using not https. Not a complete explanation, but simple enough to resolve.